# Hadoop Namenode not starting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I am getting java.io.IOException: Failed to load an FSImage file while starting Namenode

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Failed to load image from FSImageFile(file=/opt1/dfs/nn/current/fsimage_0000000000023479779, cpktTxId=0000000000023479779)
java.io.IOException: Unexpected block size: -1945969516689645797

java.io.IOException: Failed to load an FSImage file!
```

And namenode is not getting started because of this. 
I have 1 namenode, 1 seconday namenode and 3 datanodes in my cluster.

Can someone help me recover my cluster.

Comment: Which version of hadoop? have you upgraded version recently? And why multiple Namenode you need?

Comment: I use Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.4.0

Comment: @vishnu:  Can You check the namenode status?

Comment: @SreeVeni I was able to bring the cluster up by doing some changes in hadoop source code by disabling the negative check for block size.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the namenode:
**hadoop namenode -format**

Note that in order to have access permission for formatting you must execute the command as hdfs user.
In order the switch for example from cloudera user to hdfs do the following:

**sudo bash**

**su - hdfs**

---

If you still get errors regarding the datanode I probably need to clear the datanode folder:

Try deleting first the datanode folder (you can find it in the configuration file under **dos.data.dir, dfs.datanode.data.dir**).

If you have a cloudera-quickstart-vm the location is **/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/data**

Answer (score 0):

Stop all data node and secondary name node and format name node using the command:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs namenode -format
```

Restart name node and data nodes